# How many liters of blood would a small dragon have?

Tags: magic, dragons, medical, blood

Heyo! I was wondering, how many liters (measurement) of blood would a small sized western dragon have? (Only slightly bigger than a large tiger at teen age)
In addition to that, compared to human blood loss, when would the negative blood loss effects take place?
(I.e, three liters, four liters ect.? Fainting, dizzyness, health, heart rate, breathing, ect.)

Edit: Some y'all need me to be "microscopic" specific. A LARGE ADULT tiger in size. TEEN AGE. (14-17 human years) LITERS OF BLOOD.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For comparison, [other animals' blood volumes](https://www.abrint.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/ANIMAL-BLOOD-VOLUMES.pdf). Feel free to inter- or extrapolate (for a large adult dragon).

Comment: We're not here to answer questions about "European dragons" we're here to answer questions about the dragons you're building for your fictional world. What can you tell us about about them? Be specific about their size are you asking about a tiger sized juvenile or a larger adult?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! In order to get the answers you want, it is important to be understood. Try to provide as much information as possible instead of being sarcastic. Remember many of us do not speak English as a first language.

Comment: Tigers are fully grown at 5 years old. A 14-17 year old tiger is the same size as a 5 year old tiger.

Answer (score 6):

[Birds vary from 60-120ml/kilo of weight of blood.](https://lafeber.com/vet/venipuncture/)

The easy assumption is just to assume that they're similar to humans, just [doubled from the typical values.](https://www.healthline.com/health/how-much-blood-can-you-lose#noside-effects)

[image]

Since dragons are about twice as big as humans. They can lose 1.5 liters of blood without substantial issues, 3 liters of blood with major issues like rapid breathing, anxiety, and drowsiness, 4 liters of blood with severe consequences like passing out, and beyond 4 with death being likely without imminent medical aid.

Comment: Wikipedia says wild boy Siberian Tigers typically weight "180 to 306 kg". The upper limit is bigger than two humans. Even  Dwayne Johnson and Arnie Schwarzenegger in a tiger suit will barely scrape 250kg.

Comment: OP didn't clarify on tiger species.

Comment: True, but they said it was a big one.

Answer (score 3):

### So, for your first question:

A juvenile dragon that is about the size of a tiger would probably have about 18 Litres of blood. 
Pigeons have an average blood capacity of 18 ml / 100 g 
Rats have an average blood capacity of 6 ml / 100 g 
This seems to suggest if your creature is a flyer, they'll have a higher blood capacity. 
With this logic, a tiger has a blood capacity of ~ 6 Liters, so a flying creature of about the same size would have something to the tune of 18 Liters.

### For your second question:

You can almost certainly be safe in using the percentage that birds are able to lose as a baseline.
https://be.chewy.com/bird-blood-blood-loss/ 
This amount is 30%, so in theory they should be able to lose 5.4 liters of blood before suffering any major effects of blood loss.